# Hoard performance degrades severely when allocating large size chunks

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-memory-allocation, hoard

I have written below sample program in 'C' which is dynamic memory intensive and tried to benchmark the same (in terms of time taken) for the 'glibc' default allocator versus Hoard allocator.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3
  4 #define NUM_OF_BLOCKS   (1 * 4096)
  5
  6 void *allocated_mem_ptr_arr[NUM_OF_BLOCKS];
  7
  8 int
  9 main (int argc, char *argv[])
 10 {
 11     void *myblock = NULL;
 12
 13     int count, iter;
 14
 15     int blk_sz;
 16
 17     if (argc != 2)
 18     {
 19         fprintf (stderr, "Usage:./memory_intensive <Block size (KB)>\n\n");
 20         exit (-1);
 21     }
 22
 23     blk_sz = atoi (argv[1]);
 24
 25     for (iter = 0; iter < 1024; iter++)
 26     {
 27         /*
 28          * The allocated memory is not accessed (read/write) hence the residual memory
 29          * size remains low since no corresponding physical pages are being allocated
 30          */
 31         printf ("\nCurrently at iteration %d\n", iter);
 32         fflush (NULL);
 33
 34         for (count = 0; count < NUM_OF_BLOCKS; count++)
 35         {
 36             myblock = (void *) malloc (blk_sz * 1024);
 37             if (!myblock)
 38             {
 39                 printf ("malloc() fails\n");
 40                 sleep (30);
 41                 return;
 42             }
 43
 44             allocated_mem_ptr_arr[count] = myblock;
 45         }
 46
 47         for (count = 0; count < NUM_OF_BLOCKS; count++)
 48         {
 49             free (allocated_mem_ptr_arr[count]);
 50         }
 51     }
 52 }
```

As a result of this benchmark activity, I got below results (Block Size, Time elapsed for default allocator, Time elapsed for Hoard):

1. '1K'    '4.380s'    '0.927s'
2. '2k'    '8.390s'    '0.960s'
3. '4k'    '16.757s'   '1.078s'
4. '8k'    '16.619s'   '1.154s'
5. '16k'   '17.028s'   '13m 6.463s'
6. '32k'   '17.755s'   '5m 45.039s'

As can be seen, Hoard performance severely degrades with block size >= 16K. What is the reason? Can we say that Hoard is not meant for applications allocating large size chunks?

Comment: Did you look inside the source code of the allocators you are mentioning? They are free software.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9204354/841108

Comment: I attempted to replicate your test and hoard outperformed the standard allocator at every size, more so at larger block sizes. (Linux, x86-64, hoard 3.8) For example, at 32KB, hoard took 11.22 seconds. The standard allocator took 35.89 seconds.

Comment: Yeah! for line numbers. makes it oh-such-fun to cut/paste code =P

Comment: Clearly, something is not quite right here. I had a look at Hoard earlier, but something wasn't right to compile it on my machine, so never got anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice benchmarks and explanations at http://locklessinc.com/benchmarks_allocator.shtml:

> For small allocaitons, it still performs similarly to tcmalloc. However, beyond about 64KiB, it drops drastically in performance. It uses a central "hoard" to redistribute memory between threads. This presents a bottle-neck as only one thread at a time can be using it. As the number of threads increases, the problem gets worse and worse.